# How to build a table row cell by cell in Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

Let's say, I've this table:

```
+--------+----------+----
| Device | Serial # |
+--------+----------+----
| Cam1   | AB123    |
+--------+----------+----
```

Since I don't know in advance the columns that'll be displayed, I construct the table by sending just a pair of key/vale for each cell.

This is how I'm getting my data in C# code.

```
List<List<KeyValue>> myTable = deviceRepository.GetKeyValues(int facilityId);
```

Once set to the client side, data in the `myTable` will be of the following structure:

```
myTable = [
   [ { key: "DeviceName", value: "Device"}, { key: "SerialNumber", value: "Serial #"}, ..],
   [ { key: "DeviceName", value: "Cam1"}, { key: "SerialNumber", value: "AB123"}, ..],
    ...
    ]
```

In razor, I'd just have to loop through the list.

```
@foreach(var row in Model)
{
  <tr>
       @foreach(var cell in row)
       {
           <td>@cell.Value</td>
       }
  </tr>
}
```

In Angular, I don't see how to do that with directives.

```
<tr *ngFor="let myInnerList of myTable">
    //I'd like to loop through the each inner list to build each table cell
</tr>
```

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

Is it possible to get something like this? i.e if the column is the ID, display a checkbox so that the row can be selected.

```
@foreach(var cell in row)
{
   if(cell.Key == "Id")
   {
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_@cell.Value" /></td>
   }
   else
   {
       <td>@cell.Value</td>
   }
}
```

This way, the first cell for every row will display a checkbox.

Comment: What is `myListOfLists`? In your example data you have `myTable`, why is that not referenced in the `*ngFor`? What do you not understand how to do?

Comment: @Igor, thank you for pointing that how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to show, you write this but it is dependent on your arrays all being sorted the same within each array. If that is not the case you can either add code to make it so or create a filter.

This is the equivalent of the c# code you have in your question.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of myTable">
    <td *ngFor="let col of row">
      {{col.value}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it's working. I've updated the question (see update). If the column is the `ID`, a `checkbox` should be displayed instead. If you think I should start a new thread, I'll do it.

Comment: @Richard77 - that would be better addressed in a new question. You would use `*ngIf` and also `ngModel` for the value binding on the `input`.